# How to bind draggable for dynamically created elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've the following jquery:

```
$('.draggable').draggable();
$('.parent .draggable').clone(true).appendTo('.parent');
```

But now the cloned element is not allowed to drag. How can I make it draggable?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyhm5/)

Comment: Just user `$('.parent .draggable').clone().appendTo('.parent').draggable();` instead. Otherwise you're copying across any event listeners that have been bound on the original elements. This is why the original `.one` is dragged when you drag the cloned `.one` in your example. It definitely works: http://jsfiddle.net/Lyhm5/1/

Comment: @Joe I've tried that but not worked.

Comment: I've tried but not worked. Oh! wait your fiddle is working, seems .clone(true) and then .draggable() is not working.

Comment: check this not working. http://jsfiddle.net/Lyhm5/3/

Comment: but I need to use true for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question and if this will help you
but int this way all elements are draggable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.draggable').draggable();
     $('.parent .draggable').clone().appendTo('.parent').draggable();
})
</script>
```

Comment: with clone(true) is not draggable.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of initialisation and cloning:

```
$('.parent .draggable').clone(true).appendTo('.parent');
$('.draggable').draggable();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/Lyhm5/4/

If order is important to you then I would suggest you to wrap the draggable part in a separate function and call it again after cloning and appending